# Make an AnalyserNode react to an HTMLAudioElement

Tags: html, html5-audio, audiocontext

I'm trying to get a spectroscope (sine wave) to show while an audio file is playing.  The audio file plays fine but the graph only shows a flat line:

```js
function play() {
    var audio = document.querySelector('audio');
    audio.load();
    audio.play();

    var context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
    var source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);

    var analyser = context.createAnalyser();
    analyser.minDecibels = -90;
    analyser.maxDecibels = -10;
    analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.85;
    source.connect(context.destination);

    var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
    var canvasCtx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var drawVisual;

    var WIDTH = canvas.width;
    var HEIGHT = canvas.height;

    analyser.fftSize = 2048;
    var bufferLength = analyser.fftSize;
    var dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);

    canvasCtx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    var draw = function() {
        drawVisual = requestAnimationFrame(draw);

        analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(dataArray);

        canvasCtx.fillStyle = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
        canvasCtx.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        canvasCtx.lineWidth = 2;
        canvasCtx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(255, 0, 255)';

        canvasCtx.beginPath();

        var sliceWidth = WIDTH / bufferLength;
        var x = 0;

        for(var i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++) {

            var v = dataArray[i] / 128.0;
            var y = v * HEIGHT / 2;

            if(i === 0) {
                canvasCtx.moveTo(x, y);
            } else {
                canvasCtx.lineTo(x, y);
            }

            x += sliceWidth;
        }

        canvasCtx.lineTo(canvas.width, canvas.height / 2);
        canvasCtx.stroke();
    };

    draw();
}
```

```html
<audio loop src="data:audio/ogg;base64,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"></audio>
<br>
<canvas width="640" height="100"></canvas>
<br>
<button onclick="play()">Play</button>
```

Note the audio source is hardcoded here to avoid CORS issues; normally `audio.source` would be set on line 3 immediately after the `audio` var is initialized, e.g.

```js
var audio = document.querySelector('audio');
audio.src = 'https://www.example.com/foo.mp3';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AnalyserNode` is not connected yet. It needs to get the signal as an input which you want to analyze.

You can achieve that by changing the following line ...

```
source.connect(context.destination);
```

... into ...

```
source.connect(analyser).connect(context.destination);
```